# How to display records in reverse order in Laravel Admin?

Tags: laravel

Here is the package I am using https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin.
Now my entries in the admin panel are displayed in the following order

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

And I need them to be displayed the other way around

```
8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

At the same time, to sort the entries, I use the Laravel Admin extension https://github.com/laravel-admin-extensions/grid-sortable/blob/master/README.md

Comment: are you saving the order in database table ?

Comment: yes, in database

Comment: Ok, can you show the table structure here and how you are storing it into the table ?

Comment: Im try sorting by $grid->model()->orderBy('id', 'desc');

Comment: I think, there should be a different column to store the index of the row, and sort it using that column.